# How should I ground the case in a hand-wired keyboard?

Tags: pcb, esd

I'm planning on building a [Dactyl-Manuform](https://github.com/abstracthat/dactyl-manuform), a type of keyboard.  Often the electric components touch the external case (in some instances because the case becomes part of the means to support things [like keyswitch hotswap sockets](https://arnmk.com/building-a-dactyl-manuform-with-hot-swappable-sockets/)).

In my case I want to avoid soldering, so I was looking at having single-key PCBs made, with screw terminals that attach to the case, but electrically this seems equivalent.

Practically, how much of a risk of ESD is there for things like this?  Do I need to worry about the entire key matrix?  Assuming that the microcontroller has built-in ESD protection (or via something like the [unified daughter-board project](https://unified-daughterboard.github.io/#/?id=unified-daughterboard)), will I be safe?

Comment: You're concerned about electrostatic discharge damaging the components, but what about the safety risk to the user if the metal components on the exterior become energized due to a malfunction of the system? (That's the question that UL and other product standards organizations would ask.)

Comment: @Theodore That's likely no different from keyboards with touchable metal parts that you can already buy.

Comment: Looks like it's a USB device. Do you trust your PC enough to touch the connector of the USB cable while it is plugged in?

Comment: @DDuck - The design of USB connectors in general is shielded/safe enough to touch, specifically because they're meant to be (somewhat roughly) handled.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse So then your gadget - electrically connected to the USB port - should be as well.

Comment: @DDuck - that might protect me from the computer (if that's even necessary, given USB only gives 5V/2A unless you're on USB 3+ and ask for it), but doesn't protect the keyboard from me....  That also assumes my case is otherwise safe to touch (ie, no path from 5V to a touchable component).

Comment: As a side note, the design of these keyboards usually only have the GPIO pins electrically connected to the case - the 5V line is normally not used.

Comment: @Justme I haven't seen a keyboard with touchable metal parts lately, but a commercially produced product would presumably have grounding to pass some tests to meet safety standards.  A homebrew design, maybe not.  ([Here's the UL file for the keyboard I'm typing this on](https://productiq.ulprospector.com/en/profile/93386/nwgq2.e162263?term=NWGQ2&page=8)).

Comment: @Theodore Exactly, and if the keyboard metal parts are grounded to computer metal parts through cable (as is commonly done), you are safe - until for some reason the PC chassis becomes live and so do the keyboard and any other metal parts connected to computer.